# Problem in steps deriving tidal forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tidal-effect

I am looking [at this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1506/1506.04085.pdf), discribing tidal forces. I cannot get my head around how they got from $(4.2)$ to $(4.3)$:

> $$r_1^{-1}=\frac{1}{R}\left[1-2\frac{r}{R}\cos\psi+\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)^2\right]^{-1/2}\tag{4.2}$$
>
> Assuming $r$ is sufficiently smaller than $R$, we have
>
> $$r_1^{-1}=\frac{1}{R}\left[1+\frac{r}{R}\cos\psi+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)^2(3\cos^2\psi-1)\right]\tag{4.3}$$

Could you help me out here?

Comment: Hint: do a Taylor series expansion for $\frac{r}{R}$. This then exactly gives you (4.3).

Comment: (4.3) is an approximation, not an equality. The complete Taylor series has terms of order $(r/R)^n$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Binomial_series

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have a relation of the kind $r\ll R$ you can rewrite this as $\frac{r}{R}\ll  1$. If we then define $x=\frac{r}{R}$ we can express our function in terms of $x$ and since $x$ is much smaller than one we can Taylor expand the function in $x$ about zero.

So we basically have to expand the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{R}\left[1-2 x\cos\psi+x^2\right]^{-1/2}$$
As a reminder the Taylor series of $f(x)$ around zero is
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2+\mathcal O(x^3)$$
with $f'(x)=\frac{df}{dx}$.

Comment: What a better user to answer this question

Comment: @RenatoRenatoRenato This is my time to shine :)